# Can Exchange Tasks be Automated via PowerShell?

Tags: exchange, scripting, powershell, .net

I can't seem to find a way to run the various Exchange tasks (Establish E-mail Address, Remove Exchange Attributes, Create Mailbox, etc) from Powershell. It seems unlikely to me that Exchange tasks are not possible to automate; does someone have a starting point for me to automate repetetive Exchange tasks?

PowerShell would be the preferred language, but if there is no way but via .NET or similar I could go that route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can script *everything* for Exchange in PowerShell, assuming you're on 2010. You can script and awful lot in 2007 as well.

[Here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/exchange-2010-powershell-scripting-resources.aspx) is a good resource for Exchange 2010 scripting.

Also, I know that "Google it" is not an acceptable answer here, which is why I provided you with a real answer, but there are literally hundreds of useful results when googling `Exchange AND PowerShell`.

Comment: I spent half an hour googling for 'exchange "establish e-mail address" scripting OR powershell' (and variations) and found crap for results... no api documentation. I then came here and searched for exchange scripting and found crap for results. Perhaps I was too specific in my googling, but that was the specific task I wanted to perform. -5 for the question? I can understand if it had been asked 10 times before, but there is no answer to that question on serverfault... OR stackoverflow.

Comment: @Myrddin - PowerShell is so fundamentally integrated into Exchange now that if you had even browsed the documentation for it you would have seen it. People tend to downvote users that come here first before reading the docs. Glad this helped you, though.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Exchange Management Shell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123778.aspx) (It's a PowerShell module). It's installed with Exchange 2007 and above, and in fact it in essence *is* Exchange. All tasks performed in the Exchange Management Console are in fact just EMS commands. Every time you perform a task in the EMC, it will show you the exact EMS command that it is running "behind the scenes." That alone is a great learning tool.